# Overriding images in html/css

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a website in which for the mobile view I want different image and for the desktop view, I want another one.

For the desktop view, the following HTML/CSS code is working perfectly fine:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 demo-request-backgroundimage et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0 {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/contactusheader-2-min.jpg)!important;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve now for the mobile view, I want the following CSS to be called but I am not sure why the following **background image** is not getting called in the mobile view.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.demo-request-backgroundimage
{
background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mobilecontactusheader.jpg) !important;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

Comment: use "div.demo-request-backgroundimage"

Comment: Try to remove the ***!important*** from `background-image`. Not sure what the context of this but you shouldn't use ***!important***.

Answer (score 1):

you want to change `.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0` img so in `media-query` use :
**see jsFiddle:https:** https://jsfiddle.net/smuf3c3t/

```css
.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0 {
    background-image: url(https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba1.jpg)!important;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}




@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0
{
background-image: url(https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg) !important;
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="et_pb_section et_pb_section_0 demo-request-backgroundimage et_pb_with_background et_section_regular">
</div>
```

**EDIT TO COMMENT FROM YOUR WEBSITE:**
**look what happened when I resize:**
[image]

**SO remove the** `!IMPORTANT`

Comment: try to change the width in jsfiddle it woeks!!

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Its working fine in the fiddle but I am not sure why it not working in actual website. I am sending you the actual [website](https://thebettersoftwarecompany.com/demo-request/). If you inspect the header background image in mobile view, I am not sure why the CSS is not called for the mobile view.

Comment: The following CSS code for the header background image is not called. `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
div.demo-request-backgroundimage
{
  background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mobilecontactusheader.jpg) !important;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
   
}`

Comment: @user5447339 try to add this meta in <head> `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: I don't think so, it will solve the error because media queries is getting called. I think we are not using css media queries in the right way.

Comment: you give wrong path  https://thebettersoftwarecdiv.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0ompany.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mobilecontactusheader.jpg img is not getting  and also css order not is proper way

Comment: tell if it helps

Comment: I have checked your website and its working fine for me. So as I think its the problem with your cache memory, clean cache and reload again.
And for more better view please change the background size to 100% on 767, It will look better then on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
    div.demo-request-backgroundimage
    {
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mobilecontactusheader.jpg) !important;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I think `!important` present in both css codes is causing an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using more specificity outside of the media query. Try:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    div.et_pb_section.et_pb_section_0 {
        background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mobilecontactusheader.jpg) !important;
     }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I think !important present in both css codes is causing an issue

Answer (score 0):

try it with multiple classname

One Class for Normal Css
and
Other For Media Queries